# Boto3 initiate_auth raises NotAuthorizedException exception while using preferred_username as alias

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I am having a little bit of trouble with AWS CognitoIDP. As posted [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=286468), I had set `preferred_username` to be an alias, but after signing up a user and setting up his/her preferred_username, I am unable to sign in with the password.

I created a user with the preferred_username, and username as some internal UUID string. The user is reflected in cognito user pool and is confirmed using preSignUp trigger.

**SignUp Module**:

```
def sign_up(self, uuid_username, username, password):
    self.cognito_client.sign_up(
        ClientId=self.cpcid,
        SecretHash=self.get_secret_hash(uuid_username),
        Username=uuid_username,
        Password=password
    )
    user_attributes = [
        {
            'Name': CognitoAttr.PREFERRED_USERNAME.value,
            'Value': username
        }
    ]
    self.cognito_client.admin_update_user_attributes(
        UserPoolId=self.cpid,
        Username=username,
        UserAttributes=user_attributes
    )
    return
```

**SignIn Module:**

```
def sign_in(self, username, password, handle_exception=True, **kwargs):
"""

:param username: preferred_username/username of user
:param password: password of user
:param handle_exception: if false, raises cognito exception
:param kwargs:
:return:
"""
try:
    LOGGER.info("Initiate Auth Started")

    response = self.cognito_client.initiate_auth(
        AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', # with CUSTOM_AUTH, it's working because of defineAuth trigger
        AuthParameters={
            'USERNAME': username,
            'PASSWORD': password,
            'SECRET_HASH': self.get_secret_hash(username)
        },
        ClientId=self.cpcid,
    )
    LOGGER.info("Initiate Auth Ended")
    return self.encrypt_cognito_tokens(
        response["AuthenticationResult"]
    )
except ClientError as err:
    if not handle_exception:
        raise err
    return self.handle_boto3_exception(err)
```

**Not Working**:

**Context**: USER_PASSWORD_AUTH flow and login (initiate_auth of boto3) with `preferred_username` as input to the `username` parameter along with the password.

**Error**: NotAuthorizedException: An error occurred (NotAuthorizedException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Incorrect username or password.

**Working**:

**Context**: Setup a `defineAuthLambda` function which sets `issueTokens` to True, and log-ins (initiate_auth of boto3) with `CUSTOM_AUTH` flow, giving `preferred_username` or `username` as input to the username (gives token response).

Also, `admin_get_user` of Cognito boto3 also returns the response on using both username and preferred_username.

Can anyone help with what I might be doing wrong?